# Swift Firebase Query started by every change in Database

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i created an App which loads  Data from Firebase. To save ressources and make the app economical as possible i implemented queries to load suitable data for the client. Thats the code:

```
    ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "name").queryEqual(toValue: "test").observe(.value, with:{ (snapshot: DataSnapshot) in

        if snapshot.exists(){
            ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "hometown").queryEqual(toValue: "munich").observe(.value, with:{ (snapshot: DataSnapshot) in


                for users in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]{
                    if users.key as! String != userId{
                        let item = users.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                        let userid = users.key as! String
                        let Username  = item?["name"] as! String
                        let Userage = item?["age"] as! String
                        let ProfileImage = item?["profileImageUrl"] as! String
                        let firstImage = item?["firstimage"] as! String
                        let seccondImage = item?["seccondimage"] as! String
                        let thirdImage = item?["thirimage"] as! String
                        let fourthImage = item?["fourthimage"] as! String
                        let fifthImage = item?["fifthimage"] as! String
                        let sixtImage = item?["sixtimage"] as! String
                        let sex = item?["sex"] as! String
                        let gender = item?["gender"] as! String
                        let info = item?["info"] as! String
                        let userItem = UserObject(userId: userid, name: Username, age: Userage, sex: sex, gender: gender, profileImage: ProfileImage, fistImage: firstImage, seccondImage: seccondImage, thirdImage: thirdImage, fourthImage: fourthImage, fifthImage: fifthImage, info: info, sixtImage: sixtImage)
                          self.checkValidFences(userItem: userItem, gf: gf)

                    }
                }


            })
        }

    })
```

unfortunately the method loads always data when something changed in the Database. Thats the reason why i always get redundant values after changing something in the database. Is there a way to parse value just once

Comment: observeSingleEventOf

Comment: @Dominik no problem! Please also upvote the answer by clicking the arrow up (P.S. you will get a new badge!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this by [Reading data once](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#read_data_once)

> You can use the observeSingleEventOfType method to simplify this scenario: the event callback added triggers once and then does not trigger again.

---

> `observeSingleEvent(of:with:)`
>
> This is equivalent to observeEventType:withBlock:, except the block is immediately canceled after the initial data is returned.

more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/DatabaseReference#observesingleeventofwith

Answer (score 0):

You may need `observeSingleEvent` instead of `observe`

so replace every

```
.observe(.value
```

with

```
.observeSingleEvent(.value
```

See here in [Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write)